# How do I sync music to my Android with Clementine?

Tags: android, sync, music

I'm using Gnome Flashback with Ubuntu 14.04. When I plug in my Android 4.4 device by USB, it connects using MTP, and in Nautilus it looks like this:

[image: Android device]

So far, so good. In Clementine, it appears under the Devices section, like so:

[image: Clementine open Android]

If I double click on it, it does this:

[image: Clementine updating]

... and then it finishes like this:

[image: Android 0 songs]

Which all seems promising. I do actually have a bunch of songs on there that I had long ago copied over using Banshee, but I won't hold it against Clementine for not seeing them. Maybe it wants it's own special folders or something.

In any case, from this point, I can't find any option for syncing any play lists or copying music to my device. I've right-clicked on everything and gone through every menu I could find. I've tried dragging and dropping. Nothing works.

Frustratingly, when I do Google searches on how to copy music from Clementine to Android, I get a lot of hits on how to get or use Clementine's Android remote control app.

How do I get Clementine and my Android device to sync?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why Clementine doesn't find songs at first, but I can transfer musics anyway:

Right click on a track and select "Copy to device...", it might take a while, but it works, at least it did for me (You'll see a progress indicator saying "Organising files..." under play controls).

Btw my device is Nexus 4 with Android KitKat and I'm using Clementine 1.2.3.

[image: Clementine Sync]

Comment: Thanks for this response. However, was looking for a way to sync whole libraries and playlists, as is possible with Banshee, not have to handle one song at a time.

Comment: Not sure about the whole library, but I would Ctrl+A then Copy to device to sync my whole playlist.

Comment: That would copy all the files in that playlist, but then, I'd have to do that for every playlist, and then wouldn't that create duplicates of the files?

Comment: @Questioner You can "Copy to device..." when right-clicking items in the Library tab. That lets you copy albums, artists, playlists, etc.